# Verify that salt.txt was located and being used by Drupal?

Tags: 8, security

In my settings file in Drupal 8, I am specifying a location for `hash-salt` to a file outside of the docroot.

Example:

```
$settings['hash_salt'] = file_get_contents('/salt.txt');
```

I don't see anything in the status report or way to verify that Drupal was able to locate this file on the webserver and it is using it. I tried setting it to a broken path and/or file that doesn't exist, I even removed the line. However I don't see any noticeable change, so, how can you tell that this setting is being respected?

Comment: You could check this with `Drupal\Core\Site\Settings::get('hash_salt')`, somewhere in code or command line `drush ev "var_dump()"`

Comment: I tried `drush ev "var_dump()" | grep "hash-salt"` and got `var_dump() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given core.drush.inc(1168)`

Comment: I put it in an answer, there is more space.

Comment: Pretty sure that drupal dies hard and early if there is no hash salt, so that hot happening is kind of proof that it works. Try setting it to an empty string to see that "in action".

Comment: Hmm, I set it to all sorts of values that should not work. Drupal did not seem to notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check this with drush by using `Settings::get('hash_salt')`:

```
drush ev "var_dump(\Drupal\Core\Site\Settings::get('hash_salt'))"
```

Comment: Oh, gotcha, let me try that.

Comment: Result was `NULL`

Comment: OK, that might be because the $settings line didn't work. If you use the default settings, you see the hash?

Comment: No, if I comment the line out, I still get `NULL`. If I use 'install_profile', I get the right value. So the command works, just not this override.

Comment: put `echo file_get_contents('/salt.txt');` in settings.php and run `drush ev` without command, just to bootstrap drupal, then you should see the file content.

Comment: D'oh! Two things - I was using hash-salt vs hash_salt, and I was not ssh'd into the VM when executing. I get the right value when I am in the VM, but `NULL` when executing it from my host machine.

Comment: Note: forgot to use my alias for my local site. It works now.